# How to update time stamp of a all files with power shell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to write a script to update the timestamp of 5 files in a directory at a time. For example if there are 15 files in a folder then it should first update the time stamp of 5 files wait for some time or it should ask user to enter any key to update another set of 5 files followed by another wait/input and 5 files and so on.

Below I have the command to update time stamp of all the files in a folder in one go but can you please tell me the command to fulfill my requirement?

```
$currentTime = Get-Date
$folderItems = Get-ChildItem $dir

foreach ($item in $folderItems)
{
    $item.LastWriteTime = $currentTime
    $currentTime = $currentTime.AddMinutes(0)
}
$folderItems
```

Comment: You can check this Q/A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html

Comment: Adding nothing to the timestamp isn't really going to get you far. You need to count the number of processed files and decide what action to take after it (use a variable for counting and increment it each run of the loop, check it using `if`).

Answer (score 0):

With minor changes, wrapping the loop in another for loop should do the trick - for example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $folderItems.Count; $i += 5) {
    $items = $folderItems[$i..($i+4)]
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        Write-Verbose "Modifying [$($item.FullName)]"
        # Modify LastWriteTime here
    }
    Write-Host "Modified [$($items.Count)] files. " -NoNewline
    Read-Host -Prompt 'Please press any key to continue...'
}
```

This sets `$i` to zero, loops while `$i` is less than the amount of items in `$folderItems` (the Count), and increments `$i` by 5 each loop.
It then gets items in `$folderItems` with an index of `$i` to `$i+4`, and processes them.
It then writes some text, and uses `Read-Host` to wait for user-input before continuing.

However, you should know that your original loop doesn't modify the file's LastWriteTime - instead modifying the property of the PSObject you've stored in `$folderItems`.

You should probably use `Set-ItemProperty` or read the comment made by romeo-ninov about emulating `touch`.

Example:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $itemPath -Name LastWriteTime -Value $currentTime
```

You could even replace the `foreach ($item in $items) {...}` with simply piping `$items` into `Set-ItemProperty`!

Example:

```
$items = $folderItems[$i..($i+4)]
$items | Set-ItemProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $currentTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a touch replacement `Set-FileTime` from [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-touch.html)

- iterate the var $folderItems by index and
- if index + 1 modulus 5 is zero ask/wait

---

```
$currentTime = Get-Date
$folderItems = Get-ChildItem $dir

For ($i=0;$i -lt $folderItems.count;$i++){
    "{0,5} {1}" -f $i,$folderItems[$i].FullName
    Set-FileTime $folderItems[$i].FullName
    if ( ($i+1)%5 -eq 0 ){
        Read-Host "enter any key to update another set of 5 files"
        #Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    }
}
```

Comment out either `Read-Host` or `Start-Sleep`
**Edit** inserted display "{0,5} {1}" -f $i,$folderItems[$i].FullName

Sample output:

```
    0 Q:\Test\2017-04\15
    1 Q:\Test\2017-04\06
    2 Q:\Test\2017-04\01
    3 Q:\Test\2017-04\20
    4 Q:\Test\2017-04\12
enter any key to update another set of 5 files:
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the help... actually i want to see the updated time stamp of the file so added "$item | Set-ItemProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $currentTime" the command..i am satisfied with the solution

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $folderItems.Count; $i += 5) {

```
$items = $folderItems[$i..($i+4)]
foreach ($item in $items) {
    #Write-Verbose "Modifying [$($item.FullName)]"
    $item | Set-ItemProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $currentTime
    # Modify LastWriteTime here
}
Write-Host "Modified [$($items.Count)] files. " -NoNewline
dir
Read-Host -Prompt 'please enter to copy next set of files'
```

}